# VBA Range from String

Tags: vba, excel

This is kind of silly, but I've been stuck for a while in this simple statement:

```
    Dim range1 as Range
    Dim mysheet as String
    Dim myrange as String

    mysheet = "Sheet1"
    range = "A1:A10"

range1 = Worksheets(mysheet).Range(myrange)
```

I've testing all the solutions that I've found on the internet as for example [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911577/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-range-object) and [this](http://anthony-vba.kefra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1917&sid=efca1b5454c7f98554a3ed908b7b3bda), but nothing.

All the time it gives me errors: 1004 "Error defined by the application" or "object variable or with not set".

I have tried the following:

```
range1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).Range(myrange)

range1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).Range(myrange)

range1 = Sheets(mysheet).Range(myrange) (and the combinations above)

range1 = Worksheets(mysheet).Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(1,10)) (and the combinations with This/Active workbook)
```

and

```
with This/ActiveWorkbook
range1 = .Worksheets(mysheet).Range(myrange)
end with
```

None have worked.

This is a REALLY silly thing, but I've been stuck for a while now :s

Can anyone help me?

Really thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use Set to assign objects:

```
Set range1 = Worksheets(mysheet).Range(myrange)
```

Comment: Really thanks... I knew it was really simply, but I was blind.

Answer (score -1):

I get that you were stuck and I offer a slight stuckness-variant:

```
rngStr = corrSht.Range("T" & 63 + iterCnt).Address               
*** Set strRng = Range(rngStr)***
```

So sure, **** use Set to have string 'become' a range...
But that didn't work until I added "Address" to the range string in the preceding line. So hovvering the cursor over rngStr showed the range rather than the range content. I find VBA very cheeky/irritatio like this. Wish I had a better overview of the "why" as opposed to the "how to" sometimes....