# Error 91 in a function but not in a similar sub

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert a string into a range variable that I will use somewhere else. My first idea was to create a text-to-range function and to avoid dealing with the sintaxis ever again. I know it is probably a very basic question but I couldn't figure it.

My first attempt was this. It prints "indirect" were I want to (this was just a test), but running the macro step by step I see that there is an error 91 at the time to "exit" the function.

```
Dim rng As Range
rng = TXT2RNG(Range("A1").Value)

'This is the function, located in Modulo1
'Function TXT2RNG(text As String) As Range
'Set TXT2RNG = Range(text)
'TXT2RNG.Value = "indirect"
'End Function
End Sub
```

I have attempted the same but without the function, and it works as I expected.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("A2").Value)
'Set rng = Range(Range("A1").Value)
rng.Value = "direct"
End Sub
```

Summary: The second code works as a workaround but I want to know why the first one doesn't so can learn from it and use similar structures in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are simply missing a `Set` when assigning the result from the function to your variable - you do it correct in your *direct* example.
Whenever you are dealing with objects (eg worksheet, range), you need to use `Set` when assigning it to a variable. A good explanation can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928737/7599798

Omitting the `Set` will cause an error 91 when assigning it to an object variable. However, if you would declare your `rng`-variable as `Variant`, you wouldn't get a runtime error. Instead, VBA would use the so called *default property*, for a `Range` this is the `Value`, so you would end up having the content of the Range in your variable ("*indirect*" in your example). This is the reason to use the data type `Variant` only if really needed.

That said, there are at least 2 issues you should take care about:

- when you use the `Range`-function as you do, it refers to `ActiveSheet`, which is the sheet that currently has the focus. When coding, that's not always what you want, so think about if you need to approve your function. You should really take the time to read the answers of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to get an understanding.
- You should think about what should happen when the text you pass to your function doesn't contain a valid range-address. Currently, you would get a runtime error (1004). Error handling in VBA is done with `On Error`-statements. You should avoid `On Error Resume Next`.

You could change your function to:

```
Function TXT2RNG(ws as Worksheet, text As String) As Range
    On Error Goto InvalidRange
    Set TXT2RNG = ws.Range(text)
    ' TXT2RNG.Value = "indirect"
    Exit Function
InvalidRange:
    ' Think about what to do here, show a message, simply ignore it...
    Set TXT2RNG = Nothing
End Function
```

And the call to it would be

```
Dim rng as Range, address as string
address = Range("A1").Value
Set rng = TXT2RNG(activeSheet, address)
if not rng is Nothing then
    (...)
```

Comment: That was it! I didn't think I had to use Set both inside the function and in the call. As for your "best practise" recommendations, this might be too much for me at the moment. I'll go back to this in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.

From walking through your code, you're not declaring "text" as anything.

If you use the "Watches" feature, you can see it's a blank string

[image]

I believe you need to have a function that pulls the range, then a second function to pull the string of that. A `Private Sub` is much better
See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2913690/2463166

Comment: As far as I now, declaring it in the first line of the function is enough. Thanks for introducing me to the watches, it is a very useful feature that I didn't know about and felt it was missing (I come from Matlab). Regarding the answer you linked to I had seen it before but didn't really understand it, I'll check it again.